# NuGet keeps changing the hint path even though the config looks correct

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2013

We are using VS 2013 and I while I don't know if it has anything to do with it I do know VS 2012 never had this issue, When I update anything with NuGet it is deciding to change the hint path from ........\ to ..\ even though the config looks correct. What in the world could be causing it to change the hint path?

Here is our config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\..\..\Packages" />
  </config>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true"/>
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Our Super Awesome Nuget Repository" value="\\buildbox\NugetStore" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Why would it stop respecting the repository path key value?

thanks!